# Compile a COM (ActiveX) dll using .NET Core CLI (dotnet.exe) and register it with Regasm.exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, activex, comobject

I need to create a dll in C# to use in visual foxpro as COM object. I have Visual Studio Code installed with C# extension and the .NET Core Tools. The dll that I compile does not register accusing `RegAsm : error RA0000`. The procedure I took was as follow:

```
mkdir C:\Csharp\ComObject
cd C:\Csharp\ComObject
dotnet new classlib
```

In `C:\Csharp\ComObject\Class1.cs` I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ComObject
{
    [ProgId("ComObject.ClassExample")]
    [Guid("e514c7d2-ed6d-44c6-a7e2-36a272a8ba76")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ClassExample
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public int getpid(){
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            return proc.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

The `C:\CSharp\ComObject\ComObject.csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

To compile and register I ran:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Regasm.exe /codebase C:\CSharp\ComObject\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\publish\ComObject.dll
```

The output was:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 2.0.50727.8922
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004. Todos os direitos reservados.

RegAsm : error RA0000 : Falha ao carregar 
'C:\CSharp\ComObject\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\publish\ComObject.dll' porque não é um assembly .NET válido
```

If I compile the file "Class1.cs" using csc.exe it works:

```
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /t:library /out:ComObject.dll .\Class1.cs
> RegAsm.exe /codebase C:\CSharp\ComObject\ComObject.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 2.0.50727.8922
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004. Todos os direitos reservados.

(Warning about missing signature...)
Registro de tipos executado com êxito
```

What am I doing wrong using dotnet.exe?

Comment: You cannot build a [ComVisible] assembly with .NETCore.  You already noticed that Regasm.exe was missing.  Much more severe is that .NETCore does not have the mscoree.dll host available.  Maybe that will change some day, but they are not in a hurry because any machine that can execute this code always also has the full .NET Framework available.  What you in effect did by running the C# compiler by hand.  So there isn't any point in using .NETCore at all, just create the class library with the "Class Library (.NET Framework)" project template.

Comment: Thank you, I lost a lot of time trying to find a way to make it work with the dotnet.exe utility. I will just compile with csc.exe then.